# Draw on canvas from within C++ XPCOM code

Tags: c++, video, firefox-addon, mozilla, xpcom

Is it possible to draw on  element from C++ XPCOM add-on? 
Previously (long time ago probably) one could get an object of nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D interface and use ti's method PutImageData_explicit in order to draw image on canvas. Nowadays, nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D hides everything and I have no clue how to achieve this.

In general - is there a way to render a video (let's say obtained from remote host) by add-on on a web-page?

Any advice will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is [`PutImageData_explicit`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/canvas/src/CanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#3618) now. But that is a protected member.

- You may cheat the system and break the encapsulation for your purposes, e.g. by deriving and downcasting  (and now protected members are all yours).
- Or do it the hard way, and use `PutImageData` while having to mess around with `ImageData` and `ErrorResult`.

Downcasting to get to a protected member:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  protected:
    std::string myName() {
      return "Base";
    }
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    std::string myName() {
      return Base::myName();
    }
};

int main() {
  Base *base = new Base();
  Derived* derived = static_cast<Derived*>(base);
  std::cout << derived->myName() << std::endl;
  delete base;
  return 0;
}
```

PS: This works, because this still holds true `sizeof(Base) == sizeof(Derived)`. You really don't want to modify the size, e.g. by adding data members or such, unless you're a fan of segfault and heap corruption ;)

Comment: I've tried the second approach recently. Terrific results in performance (i'm drawing video frames). Can you please tell more about "upcasting" and how it can be achieved?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say downcasting, not upcasting. Corrected answer and added example of downcasting